# No Scikit-learn after I installed Anaconda in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sublimetext3

I started using Sublime Text as my Text Editor/IDE (not sure what the difference is) to do some Python projects. After watching 2 episodes of the machine learning course by Google Developers. I installed the Anaconda package which has the Scikit-learn included.

Following the video I typed:

```
import sklearn
```

This error appeared:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Is there a way to install the Scikit-learn using the Sublime Text 3 or using a different method?

Comment: where do you type `import sklearn` in the console of sublime text ?

Comment: Note also that the default build system for Python in Sublime executes `python` to run your code; if you have more than one version of Python installed (say if you're on a Mac and you installed Python 3 separately) it might be running the wrong thing.